# Unable to make a Taipy table editable

Tags: user-interface, taipy

I want to view my dataset with a table and have the option to edit it. Here is the code for my table:

```
<|{data}|table|editable=True|>
```

Setting the *editable* parameter to *True* doesn’t change anything about the table. I am running the latest version of Taipy (taipy 2.1).

Comment: Hey Areth, Feel free to join our Discord Server discord.com/invite/SNNsCDj9? and connect with like-minded individuals and collaborate on your web application buildings :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply assign a custom function to the `on_edit` property of your table to enable specific actions when a cell is edited.

The `on_edit` function is triggered when a user attempts to edit a cell. In the code below, the only purpose of the function is to update the cell with the new value provided by the user.

```py
from taipy.gui import Gui

df = {"x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     "y": [2, 4, 1, 6, 3]}

def on_edit(state, var_name, action, payload):
    id = payload["index"]
    col = payload["col"]
    value = payload["value"]

    print(f"Id: {id}, Col: {col}, Value: {value}")
    print("Row\n", state.df.loc[id, :])

    temp = state.df.copy()
    temp.loc[id, col] = value
    state.df = temp

Gui("<|{df}|table|on_edit=on_edit|>").run()
```

[image: Editable table]